# Differences between Spring security lib

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring application (not Spring Boot) and would like to add the seurity library (mainly to configure the cache setting etc and I do not want to use filter). However, I saw at least three security libs...what are the differences and which one should I choose?
The options are: `spring-security-config`, `spring-security-core` and `spring-boot-starter-security`

Comment: I don't think it won't be possible to configure cache without using filter as Spring Security altogether uses chain of filters internally.

Answer (score 4):

Differences:

**spring-security-core**  :This provide the Core Spring Security support  for **Access Control** ,**Method-level Security** and it can be used  with non-web applications as well.

**spring-security-config** :If you want use XML namespace definitions for beans related to Spring Security spring-security-config Maven dependencies is required in the application.Also it supports Spring Security’s Java based Configuration.

**spring-boot-starter-security** : This is Spring Security starter in Spring Boot  which will brings in other security related jars spring-security-core,spring-security-config and spring-security-web.